# Warning symbol in Eclipse Version: Mars.2 (4.5.2)

Tags: eclipse

I have this class in my Spring Web model-view-controller (MVC) framework. The version of the Spring Web model-view-controller (MVC) framework is 3.2.8.

I have a Warning symbol in Eclipse Version: Mars.2 (4.5.2) but when I put the mouse over the JSPs there is no message so no way to fix it.

and I cleaned the project several times with the same result.

[image]

Comment: Did you try clean?

Comment: What does the Problems view show?

Comment: Is there anything in the Problems view for it? Why does the image look strange?